# JSON callback doesn't trigger if function called from within own file

Tags: javascript, json, callback, jsonp, undefined

The title is the best way I could sum it up. It's a little fuzzy on how to explain this.
Basically, if I include the javascript file holding the JSON function from within an html file, then trigger the JSON function - callback works. However, if I just call the JSON function from within it's own file - callback never fires. Not sure if this is some sort of javascript or web browser security feature. Would be greatful for an explanation.

Here are some examples.

Working version:

json.html: (trimmed down)

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script></head>
<script>
    JSON_Object(json_url, function(json_obj) {
        alert(json_obj); // this version works!
    });
</script>
<html>
```

json.js:

```
function JSON_Object(json_url, callback) {
    // This function will return an object to the JSON data.
    json_url = json_url + "&callback=jsonCallback";

    var json_script = document.createElement("script");
    json_script.setAttribute("src", json_url);
    json_script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

    window.jsonCallback = function(jsonObjReturn) {
        // cleanup
        document.body.removeChild(json_script);
        delete window[callback];

        callback(jsonObjReturn); // use our callback function to return the data.
    }

    document.body.appendChild(json_script);
}
```

Non-Working version - Another function inside json.js:

```
    JSON_Object(content_page, function(json_obj) {
        alert(json_obj); // This version doesn't work. Never called.
    });
```

Comment: Any errors? This line: `delete window[callback];`. You probably wanted `delete window.jsonCallback;`. Shouldn't matter though.

Comment: Actually, now that I check. I do get an error on the json_url.php.
Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonCallback is not defined"
I am using Chrome and seen that in the Element View.

It should be noted that in the case it doesn't work the script is a UserScript loaded by Chrome extensions. I'm assuming this has something to do with it. Possibly scoping of some sort.

Comment: Give us some more info. How exactly the script is being loaded and what is the role of the extension? Generally extensions and background pages are separated. Thus `window` variable is something else in background and something else in extension.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I just wasn't aware that it mattered. Okay, lets try to explain this. As my earlier comment said, this is a javascript file that is a UserScript loaded in Chrome under development mode. This file is built to affect a webpage without actually being hosted on the server. IE: To modify the looks of a webpage like any other extension/UserScript. The role is to retrieve data from another server (my server) using JSON. It would make sense that the window variable is scoped. I assume that the window.jsonCallback function isn't available to the file when loaded as a UserScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found that I was right. It IS a web browser security feature for extensions.
From the following link:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Quote from the page

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

JSON falls into the above categories because it uses a function for it's callback.